# Target in Get-ItemProperty of PowerShell and how to assign values

Tags: powershell, file

Get-ItemProperty retuns Target: {}, what is this Target and if it's hash, how to assign value to it

```
PS D:\xyz> Get-ItemProperty -Path a.txt | Format-list -Property * -Force

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\xyz\a.txt
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\xyz
PSChildName       : a.txt
PSDrive           : D
.............
BaseName          : a
Target            : {}
.............
Attributes        : Archive

PS Set-ItemProperty -Path a.txt -Name Target -Value { "key1":"value1"}
At line:1 char:58
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path a.txt -Name Target -Value { "key1":"value1"}
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ':"value1"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I tried to assign value like python and it did not work

Comment: The `.Target` property contains the paths - if any - of NTFS reparse points such as symbolic links - associated with the file at hand. In Windows PowerShell, this property is _array-valued_ (so as to also support _hard links_) which is what the _for-display_ representation `{}` indicates.

Comment: Fundamentally, you cannot _set_ this property on an existing file-system item. Your specific attempt fails even earlier, because `{ ... }` is parsed as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), and the code inside `{ ... }` isn't valid PowerShell code.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do to the file?

Comment: Format-List gave all the properties of the object.  You are trying to set a property that doesn't exist.  You should be able to set a value to an existing property if you have the right permission.  In this case you have files.  If code worked in python than maybe you were running As Admin and in powershell you are not an Admin.  Try opening up powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng, as the `Format-List` output shows, a `.Target` property _does_ exist, but is in effect read-only: If you bypass the OP's syntax error and pass a formally valid value, you'll get `Set-ItemProperty : Set accessor for property "Target" is unavailable`.. Therefore, it doesn't matter whether the session is being run as admin or not.

Comment: @mklement0 : But it worked in python!!!

Comment: @jdweng I assume that "I tried to assign value like python" refers to the syntax of the `-Value` argument, and doesn't imply having achieved the entire task in Python - which is just as impossible in Python as it is in PowerShell, for the reasons stated.